# Improve Performance of execution time on 20k rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using following code on 20k rows and it takes 3 min,
how can I improve it ?

```
;WITH  abcd
        AS (
              -- anchor
            SELECT  topicid, [Description], ParentID,topicgroupfk, topicgroupfk AS "GROUPFK",
                    CAST(([Description]) AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS "Path"
            FROM    accounting.topics
            WHERE   ParentId='0' and FinancialPeriodFK=1
            UNION ALL
              --recursive member
            SELECT  t.topicid, t.[Description], t.ParentID,t.topicgroupfk,a.GROUPFK AS "GROUPFK",
                    CAST((a.path + '/' + t.Description) AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS "Path"
            FROM    accounting.topics AS t
                             JOIN abcd AS a
                      ON t.ParentId = a.topicid
                         where t.FinancialPeriodFK=1
           )
SELECT *  FROM abcd where parentid>=0
```

Comment: Hi, if you don't have any satisfactory answers here, i suggest you to try with [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) or [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) communities.

Comment: Try to execute this part of code as SQL-script using SSMS with `Include Actual Execution Plan (Ctrl+M)`. Then study your execution plan. You can add it to your question if you need somebody to comment it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What is the datatype of [ParentId]?

I bet (hope) it is an int or bigint. Therefore you can remove the quote and implicit cast here:

```
WHERE   ParentId='0'
```

- What is the datatype of [Description]?

If it is already a varchar(1000), you can remove the 2 cast as varchar(1000). If it is something smaller, you could consider changing it to varchar(1000) and then remove the 2 casts.

- Do you have a covering index on [ParentId] including [FinancialPeriodFK] with a where clause on [FinancialPeriodFK] = 1?
- where parentid>=0 is not needed
- is [topicgroupfk] an integer?
- you can also try to reduce the size and scope of the recursive CTE and get them later

  you probably only need topicid, parentid and path in the CTE and try get the other columns later with an extra join on topicid in the main select

Comment: TopicID,ParentID,Description are nvarchar(50)
TopicGroupFK is Integer

Comment: if TopicID and ParentID are numbers, change their datatype to int or smallint (big enough for 20k). It will be a lot smaller and faster. Are there proper PK or index? Do you need nvarchar? in your query you are using varchar(1000). Change it to varchar if you don't need unicode. If you set its size to 1000 or something big enough for N concatanated levels, you can remove all the casts.

Comment: What are your PK and indexes ? You should consider changid it to int and adapt the code which requiere string. A least if they are only numbers or regular (english) characters, change nvarchar to varchar. This is twise smaller. Change the size of Description to 1000 and remove the casts.

Comment: I can't change string to int because my values are like '0202001001' , So the zero before number should be kept in my db !!!
My PK and indexes are (TopicID,FinancialPeriodFK).

Comment: Did you look at all the previous comment aside from TopicID type ? Index on ParentId, remove cast, convert to varchar(1000), ... CAn you provide the query plan for this query?

Comment: Yes I did and change cast to nvarchar(1000) because using unicode and it improves my performance .

Comment: Let me know , if there is any other solution to select all the childs only without CTE hirarchical.

Comment: if it is recursive you probably need the CTE. Try to reduce the size and scope of the CTE (see my update)

Comment: put your model (topics table) and indexes in [link]http://sqlfiddle.com[link] along with uptodate query. I think you have all you need above. without query plan, it is difficult to help.